# CKEditor - How to remove leading and trailing whitespace from a selection?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, contenteditable

Is there a way to remove leading and trailing whitespace from a selection in CKEditor? Like programmatically reselect the selection without the whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This plugin](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/Smaller-Selection-trim-ending-space) trims the trailing space in a selection when selecting a word by double click. You can modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Alfonso! That plugin worked nicely. I just tweaked it a bit, including adding this bit of code to trim leading white space: //Trim left
      if ( range.endContainer.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT && range.endContainer.getText().substr( range.startOffset , 1 ) == ' ' )
      {
        range.startOffset += 1;
        custom = true;
      } Aww, no code formatting in comments :(